# Angular is undefined and Ivy workspace: <error>

Tags: angular

I used MacOS and I tried to install Angular in my terminal by typing`$ npm install -g @angular/cli`

but it kept failing and the terminal goes like this:
[image]

so, I tried again by typing `$ sudo npm install...`. it worked but the terminal says my angular is undefined and the ivy workspace: error (see in the graph)

[image]

so what should I do to correctly install angular?

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the party but maybe it could useful for future seekers :)

As pointed in [this answer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19687#issuecomment-751437744) to the similar issue, you should be inside angular project to use this command.

Also, it is is possible that you will have a problem similar to mine: you will be inside the angular project, but nevertheless you will see `Ivy Workspace: <error>` in the output.

The reason is, that [function](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/4bc0ec39b1fa9d2641ed4eef451a2d5d2af508c5/packages/angular/cli/commands/version-impl.ts#L195-L211), that should return Ivy Workspace version returns an error in case if there is no `tsconfig.json`(or `tsconfig.base.json`) in you project root folder.

You can required filename (and also if it required, because it seems like this functionality is removed in [newer versions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/HEAD/packages/angular/cli/commands/version-impl.ts)) in your `node_modules`.